# Sort ArrayList based on Another ArrayList in kotlin

Tags: list, sorting, kotlin

I have a list of `String` as below:-

```
val a = listOf("G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A")
```

I will get another list from the server. For example:-

```
val b = listOf("A", "G", "C")
```

List from the server may contain fewer elements or more elements but will not contain elements other than the first list.

So, after sorting output should be like

> // G, C, A

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You just want to sort `b` ?

Comment: Yeah, @The_ehT, Need to sort server list (list b) based on list a

Comment: I don't think "sort" is the right word here. You want to filter your source list (`a`) by keeping only elements present in your target list that you get from the server (`b`).

Comment: That's another way to look at it. What if he wants to sort `b` based on order of elements at `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` and `sorted` to achieve that easily on the condition that `a` do not have repetition -

```
val a = listOf("G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A")
val b = listOf("A", "G", "C")
val there = b.map{ v -> a.indexOf(v)}.sorted().map{v -> a[v]}
println(there)
```

Output:: [G, C, A]

Alternate sorter way as pointed by @jsamol in comment -

```
val there = b.sortedBy { a.indexOf(it) }
```

Comment: There is no need to map `b` twice. You can just use `sortedBy`: `b.sortedBy { a.indexOf(it) }`

Comment: Oh yes, that's better. I completely forgot `sortedBy`. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I don't agree the shorter code is necessary better: sorting in general makes `O(N*logN)` comparisons, where N is the number of items in the sorted list, and for each comparison it needs to perform two `a.indexOf(it)` operations, that themselves are `O(M)`, where M is the number of elements in the first list. So the resulting complexity would be `O(N*logN*2M)`. And the original approach with mapping indices has the complexity of only `O(N*(M + logN + 1))`. For large lists this difference can be significant.

Answer (score 5):

You are not trying to sort, you are trying to filter

```
fun filterByServer(server: List<String>, local: List<String>)
        = local.filter { value -> server.contains(value) }
```

`filter` takes a predicate in this case if your local value is contained on the server list

Comment: Is `toMutableList()` needed here?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera you are right is not because the filter method will return another list, my mistake is because I was writing the method using arrays and then realize it was a list, got confused with the title, thanks it should be updated now

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom comparator based on the indices of letters in the **a** list. Then use the List.sortedWith function to sort the **b** list.
e.g.

```
val a = listOf("G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A")
val b = listOf("A", "G", "C")
val indexedA: Map<String, Int> = a.mapIndexed { index, s -> s to index }.toMap()
val comparator = object: Comparator<String> {
    override fun compare(s1: String, s2: String): Int {
        val i1 = indexedA[s1]
        val i2 = indexedA[s2]
        return if (i1 == null || i2 == null) throw RuntimeException("unable to compare $s1 to $s2")
        else i1.compareTo(i2)
    }
}
val c = b.sortedWith(comparator)
System.out.println(c)
```

I've converted the list **a** to a map: Letter to Index as an optimization.

Comment: Why not use `b.sortedBy { indexedA[it] }`?

Comment: yup, `sortedBy` looks like a better (shorter) solution

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the requirement, what we're really doing here is *filtering* the first list, according to whether its elements are in the second.  So another approach would be to do that explicitly.

```
val a = listOf("G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A")
val b = listOf("A", "G", "C").toSet()   // or just setOf(…)
val there = a.filter{ it in b }
```

There's a bit more processing in creating the set, but the rest is faster and scales better, as there's no sorting or scanning, and checking for presence in a set is very fast.

(In fact, that would work fine if `b` were a list; but that wouldn't perform as well for big lists.)